# Superdirectivity Beamformer for Circular microphone array

Tags: beamforming

The matrix below represents the inverse of correlation matrix assuming diffuse noise field. I am unable to figure out the values of the elements of this matrix.

> [image: This snapshot is taken from "Design of Circular Differential Microphone Arrays," by Jacob Benesty]

how to calculate $c_{M}(\omega)$ ?

Comment: This snapshot is taken from "Design of Circular Differential Microphone Arrays," by Jacob Benesty Chapter 6.

Comment: Hi MS Ganesh, question seems very broad, can you specify what is the matrix shown and what does it represents ?

Comment: The matrix represents the inverse of diffuse noise. Its a noise correlation matrix.